# How do I detect when a Dropbox folder has been updated?

Tags: linux, synchronization, dropbox

I have a folder with files that are being sychronized between computers. After the files have been uploaded from computer A, I would like to copy them from computer B's Dropbox folder to another folder. How can I detect when the Dropbox folder has been updated? I can check the Dropbox folder periodically, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) or [incrond](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), you can use one of this tools to run a script once it detects changes in your folder. If you choose `incrond` you can run `incrontab -e` and add something like this:

```
/path/to/watched/dir IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /path/to/script
```

In the script you can, for example, start a loop while:

```
[[ $(dropbox filestatus /path/to/watched/dir) != "" ]]
```

or:

```
[[ $(lsof -p $dropbox_pid | grep 'REG|DIR.*/path/to/watched/dir') != "" ]]
```

and then:

```
cp /path/to/watched/dir /path/to/copy/dir
```

when the loop is done.

Answer (score 2):

No! (regarding the accepted answer)

Dropbox currently (it may have been different in 2012) does not trigger `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`, `IN_MODIFY`, or any of the other intuitive choices. Dropbox moves the content to temporary files which it then moves back into the Dropbox directory. The inotify event thus triggered are `IN_MOVE_TO`, and `IN_MOVE_FROM`.

so your incrontab instructions should ideally read:

```
/path/to/watched/dir IN_MOVE_TO,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, dropbox does not trigger the IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE or IN_MODIFY etc. It does trigger the IN_MOVED_TO and IN_MOVED_FROM. Verified on Debian 8.